# Marco Polo Airport Transfer from Venice

Tags: airport-transfer, italy, venice, vce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Venice Marco Polo Airport to Venice](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/venice-marco-polo-airport-to-venice)

How can I go from Venice central train station to Marco Polo airport? What is the cheapest way? What is the fastest way?